# Subsetting pandas dataframe with list returns an apparently incorrectly sized resultant dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am attempting to subset a pandas `DatFrame` **df** with a `list` **L** that contains only the column names in the DataFrame that I am interested in.  The shape of **df** is `(207, 8440)` and the length of **L** is `6894`.  When I subset my dataframe as **df[L]** (or **df.loc[:, L]**), I get a bizarre result.  The expected shape of the resultant DataFrame should be `(207, 6894)`, but instead I get `(207, 7092)`.

It seems that this should not even be possible. Can anyone explain this behavior?

Comment: If you have multiple columns with the exact same name, this will happen. You could test this with `[i for i in L if L.count(i) > 1]`, that will spit out a list that contains any duplicates.

Comment: Good, thought @scotscotmcc.  When I apply that to my list **L**, I get an empty list.  However, I think you mean to apply that to my column names in **df**, right?

Comment: So my **df** does have duplicate column names.  Thanks for your help, @scotscotmcc.  Issue solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[moving from comment to answer]

A pandas dataframe can have multiple columns with the exact same name. If this happens, passing a list of column names can return more columns than the size of the list.

You can check if the dataframe has duplicates in the column names using `{col for col in df.columns if list(df.columns).count(col) > 1}` This will return a set of every column that that comes up more than once.